# How do i change my file name after i have removed all '?

Tags: php

SORRY CAUGHT MY OWN ERROR AFTER POST

I have this code that i am running after a HTML from uploads a file to my .uploadAdmin.php section.  Im having a lot of trouble with this.

```
$clientname = $_SESSION['MM_USERNAME'];

$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

$myText = (string)$_FILES["file"]["name"];

$myText = str_replace("'", "", $myText);

print $myText; // This does come out with no '
```

My question is how do i change to file name after i have a new file name with no ' I have tried a few things including

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"] = $myText;
```

I had a comparison operator == instead of =,

Thanks Amy :)

Comment: changing the filename in $_FILES does **NOTHING** to the actual file on disk. you still need to do a move_uploaded_file() operation to get the uploaded data from the temporary file PHP produced (the filename in $_FILES[...]['temp_name']` to the name of what you want to store it as.

Comment: @MarcB  I did have the move_uploaded_file(). That wasn't my question though.  my '$_FILES["file"]["name"] = $myText;' worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've uploaded your file you need to move it from the temporary directory to the place you want to store it. This is a security feature. The uploaded file will have a temporary file name. You can change the real filename as part of the `move_uploaded_file()` operation.

```
// where to store file
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';

// name of temporary file after upload.
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

// original name of file, with apostrophes replaced
$name = str_replace("'", "", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

// move the file
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name") === false) {
   // do something if the file isn't an uploaded file.
}
```

Read the PHP reference [Handling File Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for the complete reference.